# How do I adjust (offset) colorbar title in matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib, alignment, colorbar

Given the following code:

```
imshow(np.arange(16*16).reshape(16,16))
cb = colorbar()
cb.set_label("Foo")
cb.set_ticks([0,255])
```

Which produces:

[image]

How do I adjust the colorbar text "Foo" so that it is offset to the left, betwen the 0 and 255, closer to the colorbar, reducing the un-needed whitespace?

Answer (score 83, accepted):

```
cb.set_label("Foo", labelpad=-1)
```

Negative labelpad values will move closer to the bar, positive away.

Answer (score 13):

```
cb.set_label("Foo",horizontalalignment='right')
```

The label control with this function is very poor...

---

You could do:

```
cb = colorbar()
cb.set_ticks([0,255])
ax = cb.ax
ax.text(1.3,0.5,'Foo',rotation=90)
```